# Does this fit your definition of a Callback?

Tags: javascript, oop, callback, definition

## Definition of Callback:

A Function that is set as a property within a Component.  And is usually called when some event occurs on the Component.

## For Example:

If you wish to display a dialog which reads *"I was clicked"* when the user clicks on the Component **componentB**, you would write a method stored as a variable which does this:

```
var mouseDownCallbackFunction = function() {
    alert("I was clicked!");
};
```

**Next**, you would set this function inside the component like so...

```
// Set the Component to display the dialog when the 
// user presses the mouse down on it.
componentB.setMouseDownCallback(mouseDownCallbackFunction);
```

And this would cause **mouseDownCallbackFunction** to display *"I was clicked"* in an alert box when the component was clicked.

Comment: what happens when you run this?

Comment: When the user clicks on the Component, after this code is run, a dialog "I was clicked"

Comment: Note that you can also use lambdas aka anonymous functions giving a bit less code, like this:
componentB.setMouseDownCallback( function() {
  alert("I was clicked!");
});

Comment: Ah I wondered what a Lambda function was...okay clears that up!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, that would be a valid callback. However I'm not so familar with JavaScript to say if it is or not because I'm not sure how variables are treated with respect to their memory locations.

In C/C++ you could declare a void pointer:

```
void aFunction()
{
     do stuff
}

int main()
{
    void* myCallback = &aFunction; 
    componentB.setMouseDownCallback(myCallback);
}
```

Would work.

However, despite my lack of JavaScript knowledge, I do know that

```
componentB.setMouseDownCallback(function() {
        alert("I was clicked!");
        };
);
```

is valid as well.

**EDIT** added a not to the second sentence: "I'm not so familar"

Comment: Thanks!  I work in a C++ shop, and I'm their web guy...this will help immensely in arguing my case!  Thank you starko!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is describing the exact definition of a callback...

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, technically, that's a *closure*, since it can bind to any variables in scope which are referenced.

But closures are just a better form of callback, so yes that's a callback.  A callback in C is more primitive, providing only a pointer reference to a typed function, without binding to any context.

Comment: Hmm...then I wonder how a closure is different from a callback?

Comment: ...asking question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615907/how-is-a-closure-different-from-a-callback

Comment: The other question is well answered, and it's what I meant in my first statement in reference to a closure binding variables, vs. a C callback being just a function point.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a callback is a function that's defined at a higher level than it is called.  Your client code creates the function, then passes it as a parameter to `componentB`, in order for `componentB` to call it later.

Answer (score -1):

yes, that's a callback.