# How is a closure different from a callback?

Tags: javascript, closures, callback

I asked [a question about callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615642/does-this-fit-your-definition-of-a-callback/615752#615752) and arrived at another question (see comment).
How is a closure different from a callback?

Comment: Ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070275/javascript-closures-and-callbacks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check the introduction in this: http://jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html. It can help you understand better how closures relate to functions.

Here is a set of closure examples: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures2.shtml

Basically, the callback is like a function pointer. The bit that makes it a closure, is when that function accesses anything on the context where it lives, like variables outside it. When that happens, the function will use the current values of the variables (as opposed to copy them). See example 4.

Answer (score 16):

In simple words: a callback using context variables is a closure.

Answer (score 15):

Different definitions:

[Callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_science)) -

> a callback is executable code that is passed as an argument to other code.

[Closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)) -

> a closure is a function that is evaluated in an environment containing one or more bound variables. When called, the function can access these variables.

Comment: `a callback is executable code that is passed as an argument to other code.` So, is this (callback) the same as _Higher Order Functions_ ?

Comment: So when executable code is passed as an argument to another function (ie. a callback), if that piece of executable code itself has arguments and one or more of those arguments happen to be variables within the scope of the definition of the callback, does that then make it a callback AND a closure?

Answer (score 6):

There's a good definition of closures [here](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html):

> A "closure" is an expression
>   (typically a function) that can have
>   free variables together with an
>   environment that binds those variables
>   (that "closes" the expression).

In practice, that means it's a function that has some hidden variables.

A callback is a higher-level idea.  Generally it is a function which is passed around with the intent of being called at a later time.  In JavaScript, closures are often used as callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

A callback depending on a context variable aka bound variables (== object state) will be a closure. It will be a pure function, otherwise, when it only takes free variables (== parameters).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to differentiate between those two:

Closure

> A Closure is used to extend functionality, for instance if a user clicks a button, we want something to happen on the screen, in that case, we would use a Closure where we pass the user event (a click) and then push data to the view.

Callback

> A callback is more or less similar to a closure, but it is more used to inform and provide synchronous capabilities. For instance if you perform jQuery Ajax calls, you'll have callbacks such as `success()`, `error()`, `beforeSend()` and so forth to handle the asynchronous data.

Answer (score 0):

**closure :**

- A function keyword inside another function, you are creating a closure
- Or A function return to an other function we can say closure

**Note Plain English :** A little bit difference function passing as argument in another function is callback or if define in another function is closure

```js
var length = 101;
function fn2() {
 console.log("fffxxx: "+this.length);
}
 
var obj = {
  length: 5,
  method3: function(fn) {
    fn();
    arguments[0]();
  }
};
 
obj.method3(fn2, 1);
```

**Outputहोगा

```
fffxxx:101
fffxxx:2**
```

Answer (score 0):

What is a callback function?

A callback function is a function which is:

- passed as an argument to another function
- is invoked(लागू) after some kind of event
- once its parent function completes, the function passed as an argument is then called

**in Plain English we say** 
*A callback is any function that is called by another function, which takes the first function as a parameter or function passed as an argument*

- Note : 
  **invoked** : The code inside a function is executed when the function is invoked.
  or we say like this
  It is common to use the term "call a function" instead of "invoke a function".

It is also common to say "call upon a function", "start a function", or "execute a function".

```js
 function getUserInput(firstName, lastName, age, callback2,callback1) {
    var fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;

    // Make sure the callback is a function
    if (typeof callback2 === "function") {
    // Execute the callback function and pass the parameters to it
    callback2(fullName, age);
    }
 
    if (typeof callback1 === "function") {     
    callback1(lastName);
    }
}

function callbackforlastname1(lname){
 console.log("---");
}
 
function genericPoemMaker(name, aged) {
    console.log(name + " is finer than fine wine.");
     console.log("A " + aged + " of unfortunl smile");
}

getUserInput("Avinash", "Maurya", "26", genericPoemMaker,callbackforlastname1);
```

ऐसे कॉल करते है

Answer (score -1):

I fail to see how the two are even related? A closure carries parts of a local state into a function of some sort, think of it as passing by reference.

A callback is meant to notify you about certain change and it redirects program flow. The closure could modify local state but you would never get processor time to handle that, like you would with a callback.

Comment: Someone told me the two are related here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615642/does-this-fit-your-definition-of-a-callback/615752#615752