# Is closure created when a function is called (not declared) within another function and, if so, why?

Tags: javascript, closures

From every definition I have looked up, closure is when a function is created or declared from within another function. Examples are plentiful across blogs and websites of this happening.  But what about when the function is declared outside of another function, but called then called from within a function?  For example:

```
const add = (x,y) => {
  return x + y;
};

const double = num => {
  return add(num,num)
};

let a = double(6);/*?*/
```

Does add(num, num) create closure? If so, please help me understand why.

Comment: No, there is no function created in the call `add(num, num)`, (nor in the call `double(6)`), so there is no closure.

Answer (score 2):

Closures are a product of **[lexical scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)**.

> A *closure* is the combination of a function and the lexical environment
>   within which that function was declared.

You must define a function within another one to create a closure.

What you do in your example is simply call a function that calls another and uses its return value. At no point can the `double` function access the scope of the `add` function: their scopes are distinct.

Here is a classical example of JavaScript closure

```js
var makeAdder = function(x) {
    return function(y) {
        return x + y;
    };
}

var add5 = makeAdder(5);
var add10 = makeAdder(10);

console.log(add5(2));  // 7
console.log(add10(2)); // 12
```

In both cases, the functions returned by `makeAdder`, "remember" the outer scope in which the were created (the scope created by the `makeAdder` function).

Anything that was in scope of the outer function was also in scope for the inner function, and it remains so when the inner function is returned.

Comment: Can you help me understand why here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615907/how-is-a-closure-different-from-a-callback  they state that a call back function using context variables is a closure?

Comment: Which would seem to indicate that if I write the above as const add = (x,y) => {
    return x + y;
};
const double = (num, func) => {
    return func(num,num);
};
let a = double(6, add);/*?*/

Then closure is created

Comment: @ChaseNorton That doesn't create a closure. `double` is just calling a callback. You get a closure when you do `return function(...) { ... }`

Comment: @Barmar He does return a function. But, to the point: yes ChaseNorton you create a closure but you don't take advantage of it so to speak because you never use the context from outside the function. Check out the first exemple on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: @Sébastien He doesn't return a function. `double` calls the callback, it doesn't return a function that calls the callback.

Comment: So @Sébastien, in a technical sense - closure is created but just not taken advantage of in the original example?

Comment: @ChaseNorton The distinction between function and closure is only significant if you define the function in the scope of another function, and it accesses local variables of that function.

Comment: @Barmar, you marked this as duplicate, but I feel I am asking a different question of if calling a function creates closure.

Comment: All functions are technically closures, but if it doesn't capture local variables it's not interesting.

Comment: @Barmar, while it may be only significant in that sense - is it still the fact that it creates closure?  From my understanding, closure exists when you allow a function to access scope that it originally did not have access to.

Comment: @Barmar , yes of course, you were correct.

Comment: Anyway @ChaseNorton look at my new example but mostly read the MDN and just play with it, try for yourself.

Comment: @ChaseNorton I don't know what you mean by "scope that it originally did not have access to". If it's defined within the scope, it has access to it. What makes it a closure is when you return it outside the scope, so it captures that environment.

Comment: I still consider this a duplicate. If you read and understand the first question, it should explain all you need to know about how closures work. If there's something that isn't clear there, you should comment on that question so it can be improved.

Comment: Yes, that question has been asked many times in different forms...

Comment: Sounds good.  Thank you for your input

Comment: So in reading more into this - it seems that technically - add within double is a closure.  Since both add and double do not use any global variables and thus do not provide any closure - we can not consider the functions themselves to be closures. 

So in this case, there would be 1 closure with add(num, num) - but there would be two closures if for instances the code was written as let number = 4;
const add = (x,y) => {
    x += number;
    return x + y;
};
const double = (num) => {
    return add(num,num);
};

let a = double(6);/*?*/

It may not be the